# XSLT XPATH filter expression during XSL:Choose

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xsl-choose

I have the following XML and need to filter conditionally on whether or not UnitOfMeasure has a value. If the first UnitOfMeasure where ID = 'AcceptanceCriterionValue1' contains a string with a length greater than 0, I should select that value. Otherwise, I need to select the UnitOfMeasure node value where ID = 'AcceptanceCriterionValue2'. In other words, if pH1 exists, grab it. Otherwise grab pH2:

`

```
<MaterialLots>
  <MaterialLotProperty>
   <ID>AcceptanceCriterionValue1</ID>
   <Value>
    <ValueString>5</ValueString>
    <UnitOfMeasure>pH1</UnitOfMeasure>
   </Value>
  </MaterialLotProperty>
  <MaterialLotProperty>
   <ID>AcceptanceCriterionValue2</ID>
   <Value>
   <ValueString>7</ValueString>
   <UnitOfMeasure>pH2</UnitOfMeasure>
   </Value>
  </MaterialLotProperty>
</MaterialLots>
```

`
And I need to perform the following logic. The first xsl:when statement succeeds when pH1 exists, but if it's empty the xsl:otherwise fires but doesn't return pH2 for some reason:

`

```
    <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="ns:MaterialLots/ns:MaterialLotProperty/ns:ID='AcceptanceCriterionValue1' and string-length(ns:MaterialLots/ns:MaterialLotProperty/ns:Value/ns:UnitOfMeasure) &gt; 0">
          <xsl:value-of select="ns:MaterialLots/ns:MaterialLotProperty/ns:Value/ns:UnitOfMeasure" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
         <xsl:if test="ns:MaterialLots/ns:MaterialLotProperty/ns:ID='AcceptanceCriterionValue2' and string-length(ns:MaterialLots/ns:MaterialLotProperty/ns:Value/ns:UnitOfMeasure) &gt; 0">
          <xsl:value-of select="ns:MaterialLots/ns:MaterialLotProperty/ns:Value/ns:UnitOfMeasure" />
         </xsl:if>
        </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

> I need to perform the following logic. The first xsl:when statement
>   succeeds when pH1 exists, but if it's empty the xsl:otherwise fires
>   but doesn't return pH2 for some reason

In general, an XPath expression that selects a node `$n1` when a condition `$cond` is satisfied and selects a node `$n2` otherwise is this:

```
$n1[$cond] | $n2[not($cond)]
```

Applied in your specific case, we substitute `$n1` with:

```
/*/MaterialLotProperty[ID='AcceptanceCriterionValue1']/Value/UnitOfMeasure
```

and `$cond` with:

`text()`

And `$n2` with:

```
/*/MaterialLotProperty[ID='AcceptanceCriterionValue2']/Value/UnitOfMeasure
```

**Thus, one can use a single XPath expression to select the wanted node**:

```
 /*/MaterialLotProperty[ID='AcceptanceCriterionValue1']/Value/UnitOfMeasure[text()]
|
 /*/MaterialLotProperty[ID='AcceptanceCriterionValue2']/Value/UnitOfMeasure
                      [not(/*/MaterialLotProperty[ID='AcceptanceCriterionValue1']
                                                      /Value/UnitOfMeasure[text()])]
```

**Use this single XPath expression in this simple transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select=
    "/*/MaterialLotProperty[ID='AcceptanceCriterionValue1']/Value/UnitOfMeasure[text()]
    |
     /*/MaterialLotProperty[ID='AcceptanceCriterionValue2']/Value/UnitOfMeasure
                      [not(/*/MaterialLotProperty[ID='AcceptanceCriterionValue1']
                                                          /Value/UnitOfMeasure[text()])]
    "/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When the transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<MaterialLots>
    <MaterialLotProperty>
        <ID>AcceptanceCriterionValue1</ID>
        <Value>
            <ValueString>5</ValueString>
            <UnitOfMeasure>pH1</UnitOfMeasure>
        </Value>
    </MaterialLotProperty>
    <MaterialLotProperty>
        <ID>AcceptanceCriterionValue2</ID>
        <Value>
            <ValueString>7</ValueString>
            <UnitOfMeasure>pH2</UnitOfMeasure>
        </Value>
    </MaterialLotProperty>
</MaterialLots>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
pH1
```

**If you replace in the XML document**

```
<UnitOfMeasure>pH1</UnitOfMeasure>
```

with:

```
<UnitOfMeasure/>
```

**again the correct result is produced:**

```
pH2
```

Comment: This fixed it. Thank you so much for your help! I knew I didn't need a loop since I knew the exact value of the nodes to filter on, but couldn't figure out the if-else logic. XSLT can be tough!

Answer (score 0):

The expression to test for your first measure is this...

```
<xsl:when test="string-length(ns:MaterialLots/ns:MaterialLotProperty[ns:ID='AcceptanceCriterionValue1']/ns:Value/ns:UnitOfMeasure) > 0">
```

However, it might be slightly better to use a variable, to avoid some repetition.

```
<xsl:variable name="uom1" select="ns:MaterialLots/ns:MaterialLotProperty[ns:ID='AcceptanceCriterionValue1']/ns:Value/ns:UnitOfMeasure" />
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="string-length($uom1) > 0">
        <xsl:value-of select="$uom1" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="ns:MaterialLots/ns:MaterialLotProperty[ns:ID='AcceptanceCriterionValue2']/ns:Value/ns:UnitOfMeasure" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Alternatively, you could make use of a `xsl:key`

```
<xsl:key name="MLP" match="ns:UnitOfMeasure" use="../../ns:ID" />
```

Then you could do this

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="string-length(key('MLP', 'AcceptanceCriterionValue1')) > 0">
        <xsl:value-of select="key('MLP', 'AcceptanceCriterionValue1')" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('MLP', 'AcceptanceCriterionValue2')" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to iterate through each MaterialLotProperty.
Also, check length of UnitOfMeasure first, before the choose.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns="foo">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xml>
    <xsl:for-each select='//ns:MaterialLotProperty'>
        <xsl:if test='string-length(ns:Value/ns:UnitOfMeasure) &gt; 0'>
            <xsl:element name='output'>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="(ns:ID='AcceptanceCriterionValue1')">
                        <xsl:value-of select='ns:Value/ns:UnitOfMeasure'/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="(ns:ID='AcceptanceCriterionValue2')">
                        <xsl:value-of select='ns:Value/ns:UnitOfMeasure'/>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xml>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This second XSL outputs the first non-blank UnitOfMeasure.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns="foo">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xml>
    <xsl:for-each select='//ns:MaterialLotProperty/ns:Value[string-length( ns:UnitOfMeasure ) &gt; 0]/ns:UnitOfMeasure'>
        <xsl:if test='(position() =1)'>
            <xsl:element name='output'>
                <xsl:value-of select='.'/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xml>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I like your solution. Unfortunately, when both values pH1 and pH2 both exist, it's grabbing both of the values. I only want the first one if it exists and the second one if the first one is an empty string. This is the issue I've been facing all along. I can get the first value and the second value and both if they both exist. But I can't figure out how to get one or the other but not both.